# what is reasons of this errors "more than 'max_user_connections' active connections"?

Tags: php, sql-server

User cscredu_user already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections . What is the actual reason of this error ? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`max_user_connections`: the number of simultaneous connections to the server by an account.

You can find the number by next sql:

```
SELECT max_user_connections FROM mysql.user
WHERE user='your_username' AND host='your_access_host';
```

If you want to unlimited, just execute next sql, set to `0`:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO your_username@your_access_host WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```